# Do the fonts Bebas Neue and Klinic Slab pair well?

Tags: typography

I am trying to find two fonts to use on my resume.

[Bebas Neue](http://fontfabric.com/bebas-neue/)

[Klinic Slab](http://www.losttype.com/klinic/)

[image]

Comment: I'd say, yes, there's enough contrast between the two so they don't compete. That said, font pairings are as much subjective as objective and context dependent, so may not be a great question for the SE format.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. Wasn't sure what kind of stuff to ask here. Thanks

Comment: I second DA01. Looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I would tweak a few things around (lower the parenthesis and dash a bit for old-style figures) but I think in general it looks fine. My main concern would be if you want to scale this style to other things than your resume later on...Bebas is caps only so I find that limiting and avoid using Bebas usually for that reason.